# Content-Length being set incorrectly

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I have run into a strange issue where my web browser control is sending requests where the "Content-Length" header is always 1 byte too big. This is ok for normal HTTP requests but HTTPS requests don't work with this error.

Basically, here is what I did:

Click a post button in the web browser

Handle the beforeNavigate2 event, cancel the current request, and create a new `.navigate()` with the same postdata, headers, etc.

Now when inspecting the request with fiddler, I can see that the content length is 653 (for the actual data), but the content length header is always 1 digit more.

Why does this happen?

Comment: To be honest, it seems more likely that you're misinterpreting the Fiddler data... can you give an example (with a short postdata)?

Comment: Hi, the problem was as I suspected, but I was able to fix it by setting the content-length to always be actual lenght -1.

Comment: That still sounds pretty unlikely to me. Do you have a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: My program is very long and complex but its pretty much how I explained it in the question. The WebBrowser control is very buggy when it comes to modfying requests so it could be a control bug.

Comment: I dare say your full program is long and complex - but it sounds like you should be able to reproduce the problem with a short but complete program. I'm more inclined to suspect there's a bug in your code than the framework... I'm not saying that's *definitely* the case, of course, but currently you haven't really given any evidence.

Comment: Look, all I did was pass an byte[] which when translated to string has a length of 300, but the content-length is set to 301. Before navigate 2 event is hidden and I can see why, its buggy as hell.

Comment: When dealing with strings, COM-wrapped controls and the digit 1, always consider null termination which accounts for an extra byte in the string length.